# sql query to determine the age difference between the oldest member and the youngest member

Tags: sql, difference

I'm trying to determine the age difference between the youngest child member and oldest child members in a Household. I'm able to pull all member data I want/need but I do not know how to find the difference between in their ages...I just don't know where to go from here:

```
SELECT     Household.Name,Member.RecStatus, Member.FirstName, Member.LastName,  
                      Member.SSN, Member.DOB, DATEDIFF(Year, Member.DOB, GETDATE()), RelationshipCat.RelationshipDesc, FinancialPlanner.LastName AS Expr1
FROM         Member AS Member INNER JOIN
                      Household AS Household ON Member.HouseholdID = Household.HouseholdID INNER JOIN
                      RelationshipCat AS RelationshipCat ON Member.Relationship = RelationshipCat.Relationship INNER JOIN
                      FinancialPlanner AS FinancialPlanner ON Household.FinancialPlannerID = FinancialPlanner.FinancialPlannerID
                      Where member.Relationship in ('2', '14', '47', '69', '55', '12', '70')
```

Comment: How do you determine which members of a household that are children?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MIN` and `MAX` to find youngest and oldest man:

```
CREATE TABLE TestAge ( Age INT );
INSERT INTO TestAge VALUES (12), (13), (18), (24), (42), (17);

SELECT MAX(Age) - MIN(Age) AS [Age Diff]
FROM TestAge
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68e261/2)**